# Bounded norms on Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

In Rudin's Functional Analysis text, there's a theorem on page 45:

If $\Gamma$ is a collection of continuous linear maps from a F-space space $X$ to a topological vector space $Y$, and if $\{Tx: T \in \Gamma \}$ is bounded in $Y$ for each $x$ in $X$, then $\Gamma$ is equicontinuous.

I don't understand the following conclusion that Rudin makes from this:

If $X$ and $Y$ are both Banach, and if $\sup_{T \in \Gamma}\|Tx\| < \infty$ for all $x$ in $X$, then there exists $M<\infty$ such that $\|Tx\| \le M$ if $\|x\|≤1$ and $T$ in $G$.

How does this follow?

Furthermore, he claims that this implies $\|Tx\| \le M\|x\|$ if $x \in X$ and $T \in \Gamma$. How?

Comment: How are you defining "bounded" in a general topological vector space?

Comment: $E$ is bounded if for all open sets $V$ containing $0$ there exists $s>0$ such that $E$ is contained in $tV$ for all $t>s$.

Comment: Anyway, the work is to see that a set of linear maps between normed spaces is equi-continuous if and only if there is a common bound of their operator norm. This should follow from unpacking definitions however, for "only if" look at equi-continuity at $0$.

Comment: A subset $S$ of a normed vector space is bounded if and only if $\{ \lVert x\rVert : x \in S\}$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. (Plug in the definitions, recalling how the neighbourhoods of $0$ are related to the norm.) For families of linear maps between normed spaces, being equicontinuous means there is an $\varepsilon > 0$, such that the $\varepsilon$-ball around $0$ of $X$ is mapped into the unit ball of $Y$ by all maps in the family. By the definition of the operator norm, that means the norms in the family are bounded by $1/\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N_x=\sup_{T \in \Gamma}||Tx|| < \infty$, this  implies that $\{\|T(x)\|<N_x,T\in\Gamma\}$ so we deduce that $\{T(x),T\in \Gamma\}$ is bounded for every $x$ and $\Gamma$ is equicontinuous.

This implies that there exists $c$ such that $\|x\|< 2c$ implies that $\|T(x)\|<1$ for every $T\in \Gamma$, if $\|x\|=1, \|cx\|=c<2c$, we deduce that $\|T(x)\|={1\over c}\|T(cx)\|\leq {1\over c}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how we conclude that $\{T(x), T \in \Gamma\}$ is bounded? Also, I don't think the operator norm $||T||$ has even been defined yet at this point in the book...

Comment: It's still not clear to me why $||Tx|| < N_x$ for all $T \in \Gamma$ implies that $\{Tx: T \in \Gamma\}$ is a bounded set in Y, for all $x \in X$. Is the original theorem being applied to $Y$ and $\mathbf{R}$?